# C++ Socket recv can't keep up with send on certain computers

Tags: c++, c, sockets, network-programming

I have a simple TCP/UDP socket code, all it does is send a timestamp in microseconds, and then the receiving side takes a timestamp when a packet arrives and shows the microseconds diff between them.

On certain computers, the diff will be 0 most of the time with occasional spikes, and on other computers I've tested the diff will gradually become bigger, and the reading side will not keep up with the sending side.

I have tested this with Python as well, and found the same behavior. I've tested all the possible socket types and flags. This feels like a system configuration issue. I've tested on Windows 7/8/10 and Server 2012 R2. This behavior does and does not occur on every one of them (big company, a lot of computers tested).

I've also tried some Registry optimizations, but none seemed to help since this issue happens in TCP and UDP as well. I'll attach my C++ code for example, you can run this on your computer and see what happens, any of the 2 options is likely.

**Sender:**

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#include "winsock2.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include "Mstcpip.h"
#include "WS2tcpip.h"

#define BUFFSIZE 16

const char* getSocketErrorDescription(int socketError)
{
    static  char msg[100];
    sprintf(msg, "Winsock error code");
    return msg;
}

int write_select(UINT_PTR filedes, long microsSec)
{
    fd_set set;
    struct timeval timeout;
    FD_ZERO(&set);
    FD_SET(filedes, &set);
    timeout.tv_sec = 0;
    timeout.tv_usec = microsSec;

    /* select returns 0 if timeout, 1 if input available, -1 if error. */
    return select(FD_SETSIZE, NULL, &set, NULL, &timeout);
}

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    WSADATA data;
    WSAStartup(version, &data);
    sockaddr_in localAddr;
    ZeroMemory(&localAddr, sizeof(localAddr));

    localAddr.sin_family = PF_INET;
    localAddr.sin_port = htons((u_short)5555);
    //localAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    InetPton(PF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &(localAddr.sin_addr));

    SOCKET sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sockfd == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "SocketClient::create socket failed" << std::endl;
    }

    if (connect(sockfd, (sockaddr*)&localAddr, sizeof(localAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << ("connect failed. %s", getSocketErrorDescription(WSAGetLastError())) << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Sending..." << std::endl;
    while (true)
    {
        counter++;
        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto duration = now.time_since_epoch();
        auto microseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(duration);

        __int64 s_t = microseconds.count();
        std::string strMsg = std::to_string(s_t);
        while (write_select(sockfd, 10000) == 0)
        {
            std::cout << ("%s: timeout", strMsg.c_str()) << std::endl;
        }
        if (send(sockfd, strMsg.c_str(), BUFFSIZE, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            int socketError = WSAGetLastError();
            std::cout << ("failed to send string. %s", getSocketErrorDescription(socketError)) << std::endl;;
        }
        Sleep(2);
        std::cout << "Counter: " << counter << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**Receiver:**

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#include "winsock2.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include "Mstcpip.h"
#include "WS2tcpip.h"

#define BUFFSIZE 16
const char* getSocketErrorDescription(int socketError)
{
    static  char msg[100];
    sprintf(msg, "Winsock error code");
    return msg;
}

int read_select(UINT_PTR filedes, long microsSec)
{
    fd_set set;
    struct timeval timeout;
    FD_ZERO(&set);
    FD_SET(filedes, &set);
    timeout.tv_sec = 0;
    timeout.tv_usec = microsSec;

    /* select returns 0 if timeout, 1 if input available, -1 if error. */
    return select(FD_SETSIZE, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
}

void parseMsg(std::string& buffer, std::vector<std::string>* messages_list)
{
    while (buffer.size() >= 16)
    {
        messages_list->push_back(buffer.substr(0, 16));
        buffer.erase(0, 16);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    //std::ofstream res_file;
    //res_file.open("D:\\cpp_times.txt");
    WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    WSADATA data;
    WSAStartup(version, &data);
    sockaddr_in localAddr;
    ZeroMemory(&localAddr, sizeof(localAddr));

    localAddr.sin_family = PF_INET;
    localAddr.sin_port = htons((u_short)5555);
    //localAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    InetPton(PF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &(localAddr.sin_addr));

    SOCKET sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sockfd == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "SocketClient::create socket failed" << std::endl;
    }

    if(bind(sockfd, (sockaddr*)&localAddr, sizeof(localAddr)) != 0)
    {
        int socketError = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cout << ("bind  failed  %s", getSocketErrorDescription(socketError)) << std::endl;
    }
    if (listen(sockfd, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << ("listen  failed") << std::endl;
    }

    int clilen = sizeof(localAddr);
    SOCKET new_socket = accept(sockfd, (sockaddr*)&localAddr, &clilen);
    if (new_socket < 0)
        std::cout << "ERROR on accept" << std::endl;


    std::cout << "Listening..." << std::endl;
    while (true)
    {
        int nbytesRead = 0;
        std::string m_buffer;
        char recvbuf[BUFFSIZE];
        // Receive until the peer closes the connection 
//      if (read_select(new_socket, 10000))
//      {
//          nbytesRead = recv(new_socket, recvbuf, BUFFSIZE, 0);
//          
//      }
//      else
//      {
//          //std::cout << ("%s: timeout", strMsg.c_str()) << std::endl;
//          continue;
//      }
        nbytesRead = recv(new_socket, recvbuf, BUFFSIZE, 0);
        if (nbytesRead > 0)
        {
            std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            auto duration = now.time_since_epoch();
            auto microseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(duration);

            __int64 r_t = microseconds.count();
            std::string strMsg = std::to_string(r_t);
            m_buffer.append(recvbuf, nbytesRead);
            std::vector<std::string> message_list;
            parseMsg(m_buffer, &message_list);
            for (auto msg : message_list)
            {
                counter++;
                __int64 diff = r_t - _atoi64(msg.c_str());
                std::cout << "SendTime: " << msg.c_str() << " ReceiveTime: " << r_t << " Diff: " << diff << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Counter: " << counter << std::endl;
                //res_file << diff << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to send messages over TCP. TCP isn't a message protocol, so you have to implement one yourself and layer it on top of TCP.

Answer (score 2):

I see several problems with this code.  But most notably, on the sender side, your call to `send()` is wrong.

```
if (send(sockfd, strMsg.c_str(), BUFFSIZE, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
```

You are sending the contents of a `std::string` that is not guaranteed to be `BUFFSIZE` in size.  It may be shorter, it may be longer, depending on the actual numeric value of `s_t`.  You should be using `strMsg.size()` instead (with or without `+1`, depending on whether you want to send the null terminator or not).

```
if (send(sockfd, strMsg.c_str(), strMsg.size()+1, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
```

And actually, you should be calling `send()` in a loop, since it is not guaranteed to send as many bytes as you request, it may send fewer, so you would have to call `send()` again to finish sending the remaining bytes.

On the receiving side, you are correctly using the return value of `recv()` to know how many bytes have been received on each call, and you are *trying* to buffer the received bytes and parse only multiples of 16 bytes that you want.  This is a good approach in general. However, your `m_buffer` variable is declared in the wrong scope, so it gets destroyed after every `recv()` call. And an `__int64` in string format can be fewer than or more than 16 character. It can be as few as 1 character, or as many as 19 characters (20 if you count the leading `-` of a negative value).

For what you are attempting, there is no need to convert an `__int64` to a `std::string` for transmission and then back to an `__int64`.  You can just transmit the `__int64` in its original binary form as-is.

Other errors I see include using the `timeval` parameter of `select()` incorrectly, using `std::cout` incorrectly, and lack of good error handling.

Try something more like this instead:

**Sender:**

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#include "winsock2.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include "Mstcpip.h"
#include "WS2tcpip.h"

const char* getSocketErrorDescription(int socketError)
{
    static  char msg[100];
    sprintf(msg, "Winsock error code %d", socketError);
    return msg;
}

int write_select(SOCKET sockfd, long microSec)
{
    fd_set set;
    struct timeval timeout;
    FD_ZERO(&set);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &set);
    timeout.tv_sec = microSec / 1000000;
    timeout.tv_usec = microSec % 1000000;

    /* select returns 0 if timeout, 1 if input available, -1 if error. */
    return select(0/*sockfd+1*/, NULL, &set, NULL, &timeout);
}

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    WSADATA data;

    int res = WSAStartup(version, &data);
    if (res != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "WSAStartup failed. " << getSocketErrorDescription(res) << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    sockaddr_in localAddr;
    ZeroMemory(&localAddr, sizeof(localAddr));

    localAddr.sin_family = PF_INET;
    localAddr.sin_port = htons(5555);
    //localAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    InetPton(PF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &(localAddr.sin_addr));

    SOCKET sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sockfd == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "socket failed. " << getSocketErrorDescription(WSAGetLastError()) << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    if (connect(sockfd, (sockaddr*)&localAddr, sizeof(localAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "connect failed. " << getSocketErrorDescription(WSAGetLastError()) << std::endl;
        closesocket(sockfd);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "Sending..." << std::endl;
    bool keepGoing = true;
    do
    {
        counter++;
        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto duration = now.time_since_epoch();
        auto microseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(duration);

        int64_t s_t = microseconds.count();

        while (write_select(sockfd, 10000) == 0)
        {
            std::cout << s_t << ": timeout" << std::endl;
        }

        char *ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&s_t);
        size_t size = sizeof(s_t);
        do
        {
            res = send(sockfd, ptr, size, 0);
            if (res == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                std::cout << "send failed. " << getSocketErrorDescription(WSAGetLastError()) << std::endl;
                keepGoing = false;
                break;
            }
            ptr += res;
            size -= res;
        }
        while (size > 0);

        if (!keepGoing)
            break;

        Sleep(2);
        std::cout << "Counter: " << counter << std::endl;
    }
    while (true);

    closesocket(sockFd);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

**Receiver:**

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#include "winsock2.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include "Mstcpip.h"
#include "WS2tcpip.h"

#define BUFFSIZE 16

const char* getSocketErrorDescription(int socketError)
{
    static  char msg[100];
    sprintf(msg, "Winsock error code %d", socketError);
    return msg;
}

int read_select(SOCKET sockfd, long microsSec)
{
    fd_set set;
    struct timeval timeout;
    FD_ZERO(&set);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &set);
    timeout.tv_sec = microsSec / 1000000;
    timeout.tv_usec = microsSec % 1000000;

    /* select returns 0 if timeout, 1 if input available, -1 if error. */
    return select(0/*sockFd+1*/, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
}

void parseMsg(std::string& buffer, std::vector<int64_t>& messages_list)
{
    while (buffer.size() >= sizeof(int64_t))
    {
        int64_t value;
        std::memcpy(&value, buffer.data(), sizeof(value));
        messages_list.push_back(value);
        buffer.erase(0, sizeof(value));
    }
}

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    //std::ofstream res_file;
    //res_file.open("D:\\cpp_times.txt");
    WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    WSADATA data;

    int res = WSAStartup(version, &data);
    if (res != 0)
    {
        std::cout << ("WSAStartup failed. " << getSocketErrorDescription(res) << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    sockaddr_in localAddr;
    ZeroMemory(&localAddr, sizeof(localAddr));

    localAddr.sin_family = PF_INET;
    localAddr.sin_port = htons(5555);
    //localAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    InetPton(PF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &(localAddr.sin_addr));

    SOCKET sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sockfd == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "socket failed. " << getSocketErrorDescription(WSAGetLasstError()) << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    if (bind(sockfd, (sockaddr*)&localAddr, sizeof(localAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "bind failed. " << getSocketErrorDescription(WSAGetLastError()) << std::endl;
        closesocket(sockfd);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    if (listen(sockfd, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "listen failed. " << getSocketErrorDescription(WSAGetLastError()) << std::endl;
        closesocket(sockfd);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    int clilen = sizeof(localAddr);
    SOCKET new_socket = accept(sockfd, (sockaddr*)&localAddr, &clilen);
    if (new_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "accept failed. " << getSocketErrorDescription(WSAGetLastError()) << std::endl;
        closesocket(sockfd);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "Listening..." << std::endl;

    std::string m_buffer;
    char recvbuf[BUFFSIZE];

    while (true)
    {
        int nbytesRead;

        // Receive until the peer closes the connection 
//      if (read_select(new_socket, 10000))
//      {
//          nbytesRead = recv(new_socket, recvbuf, BUFFSIZE, 0);
//      }
//      else
//      {
//          //std::cout << strMsg << ": timeout" << std::endl;
//          continue;
//      }

        nbytesRead = recv(new_socket, recvbuf, BUFFSIZE, 0);
        if (nbytesRead <= 0)
        {
            if (nbytesRead < 0)
                std::cout << "recv failed. " << getSocketErrorDescription(WSAGetLastError()) << std::endl;
            else
                std::cout << "client disconnected" << std::endl;
            closesocket(new_socket);
            break;
        }

        m_buffer.append(recvbuf, nbytesRead);

        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto duration = now.time_since_epoch();
        auto microseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(duration);

        __int64 r_t = microseconds.count();

        std::vector<int64_t> message_list;
        parseMsg(m_buffer, message_list);

        for (auto msg : message_list)
        {
            counter++;
            int64_t diff = r_t - msg;
            std::cout << "SendTime: " << msg << " ReceiveTime: " << r_t << " Diff: " << diff << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Counter: " << counter << std::endl;
            //res_file << diff << std::endl;
        }
    }

    closesocket(sockfd);
    WSACleanup();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yea I know but ths message is of fixed size of 16 so its meaningless.

Comment: @עידןבוגנים: You seem to have overlooked Remy's last two sentences.

Comment: @עידןבוגנים There is nothing in the sender code you have shown that ensures it sends a fixed 16 bytes per `__int64` string. It is only on the receiver side that you are using a fixed 16 byte buffer to receive bytes in. In any case, I have updated my answer with more details, and a new code example.

Comment: @עידןבוגנים Then where's the code to ensure your sender always sends exactly 16 bytes and your receiver always receives exactly 16 bytes? Your sender, as far as I can tell, sends `strMsg.c_str()` bytes. And your received receives *up to* 16 bytes. Also, your code is a weird hybrid between blocking and non-blocking. That may not matter if it's just for test/experimental purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, I think your missing the point though, this code works exactly as I'd expect it to work, my issue is why on some computers recv can't keep up with the packets.

Comment: Probably because your sender is slamming the connection with lots of data at microsecond/millisecond intervals, and the receiver is reading small amounts of data at a time. Slow down the sender, and/or speed up the receiver (ie, try using a much larger recv buffer than 16 bytes, say 256 bytes or more)